# How to determine if child component form is valid in parent component when using reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-validation

I am using Angular 5 with Reactive forms

Child component class:

```
export class UserEditor implements OnInit {

    public userForm: FormGroup;

...

ngOnInit() {
    this.createFormControls();
    this.createForm();
}
createFormControls() {
    this.userName = new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(4)
    ]);
    this.firstName = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.lastName = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.email = new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern("[^ @]*@[^ @]*")
    ]);

}
createForm() {
 this.userForm = new FormGroup({
      userName: this.userName,
      name: new FormGroup({
        firstName: this.firstName,
        lastName: this.lastName,
      }),
      email: this.email,
    });
}
```

In my parent component form I have buttons that are disabled if the above validators is not valid

In the parent component html:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm  btn-primary" (click)="saveUser()" [disabled]="!userListChild?.userForm.valid">
```

In the parent component class:

```
export class UserList implements OnInit {
     @ViewChild(UserEditor) userListChild: UserEditor;
```

Everything works well however I get the well known error

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false

I tried the change detection solution listed in this blog but it didn't help.

https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

So I am stuck unless if I ignore the error as the app works fine with the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an answer to list several solutions :

1 - Try replacing `ngOnInit` with `ngAfterViewChecked`

2 - In your `ngOnInit`, try adding a `setTimeout(() => /* calls */)` where you put both of your method calls in the timeout

Answer (score 0):

It would be really simpler if you were using this library  https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form

I've replied to a very similar answer than this one here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56375605/2398593 so I don't think it would be of any use to provide some more code than there.

Please also check the demo I've made for that answer here https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-question-angular-2-large-scale-application-forms-handling where you'll be able to see something similar as your structure

[image]

Notice the errors part? From the parent component you'll have access to it and be able to see what's wrong into your form even if you've got sub forms!