# Using formcontrol in nested children

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have this situation:

parent-component :

```
 <form [formGroup]="xyz">
   <my-child-component formControlName="childData"></my-child-component>
</form>
```

my-child-component:

```
  <some other markup/>
  <third-party-component formControlName="somedata"></third-party-component>
```

The issue here is that I have implemented ControlValueAccessor in my-child-component and can use it as part of the reactive form defined in the parent.

However, the third party component nested instead my child component also requires a form control reference.  However my form is not defined at the my-child-component level.

Question - is there a way to create and use a formgroup and formcontrol without actually defining it inside a form?  In the above I need communicate dirty and pristine state from the third-party component to the parent.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I've replied to a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56375605/2398593 and you can check out this library to achieve that in a really simple way https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form