# Angular child form control/group values and errors bubbling up to parent

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular-material

**My requirement**: A single FormControl must contain the answer of multiple inputs (*multiple child FormControls or FormGroups*).

That is because multiple controls must feed into the top level (parent) FormControl, and the value of the parent level FormControl must be filtered/manipulated to fit the required format.

A good example would be a split up phone input, with a **Country code dropdown**, **phone number input**, and **extension input**, all being separate from one another, but together in a FormGroup. As any of those input values change, the parent level FormControl value must change as well.

In addition to the values ***bubbling*** up, the errors of the child controls must bubble up to the parent FormControl too.

Right now I have the parent FormControl listening to the value changes of a FormGroup with the country code, phone number, and extension inputs. Then, using ControlValueAccessor on a component, that writes the value of the parent FormControl when FormGroup ValueChanges.

I need a way to achieve the desired outcome, but also a way to do even more complex controls and FormGroups. Think multiple degrees of nested FormControls and/or FormGroups.

**Environment**

- Angular 7
- Material 7
- NGRX 6

Answer (score 0):

Initially trying to come up with a nice solution to handle breaking down huge forms into sub forms (sub components...), we came up with a solution for that but **also** to have access to nested errors.

We've build a library for that https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form that will give you way more than just access to nested errors and you can check the official demo here: https://cloudnc.github.io/ngx-sub-form/listings/new (edit the form and see the errors displayed)

I've also replied to a similar SO question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56375605/2398593 and built a demo for that question here (which also showcase the nested errors functionality) https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-question-angular-2-large-scale-application-forms-handling

Hope it helps!

**Edit:**

If you want to go further, I've just published a blog post to explain a lot of things about forms and ngx-sub-form here https://dev.to/maxime1992/building-scalable-robust-and-type-safe-forms-with-angular-3nf9