# Reactive Forms : Pattern Validation not working in child component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In the above example,I have a reactive form with nested form groups.address-form child component is used for the nested form group.The validation is being done in the parent component.Everything seems working except the pattern validation.**The validation for required works fine but the pattern validation does not work**.

I have used the validators.compose to club together required validation and pattern validation.Is there anything i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Your demo works for me. When I put 2222222222222222, it accepts. And it fails with message, 'Address should follow the pattern', if otherwise. By the way, both 'required' and pattern validators work from my Chrome browser. So, what is the question again?

Comment: I was just thinking that i would get both the error messages..Does this pattern accepts empty string?..Sorry if this is lame i am new to this

Comment: Have you changed something in Stackblitz sample?

Comment: yes I removed the required validation

Comment: Passing formGroup to a child component is a bad practice because you let a child access an object which has way more than it should. I've made a full post about that here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56375605/2398593 and you should also just check https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form library for that

Answer (score 1):

As for me, you validation pattern, enter: `1234567890123456`.
What kind of information do you want to validate?)
Also you can replace it with

```
address1: ['',Validators.pattern('^\\d{16}$')]
```

Comment: Does this pattern accepts empty string?I tried removing required validation but the pattern validation does not trigger

Comment: It triggers when you start typing)

Comment: How does this pattern '^\\d{16}$' different from OP's regex? Both looks the same. IMO, this does answer the question as well. Does it? Based on the source https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/issues/605, Pattern validators do not work on empty fields.

Comment: Thanks for the help..Can you please suggest me how to move the validators to the child component ?

Comment: easy) you can pass formControl to child component with @Input. 
Good example: https://medium.com/@joshblf/using-child-components-in-angular-forms-d44e60036664