# Force child input to have the same "states" as wrapping/ parent control

Tags: angular, angular-material

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mneerk?file=app%2Fform-field-appearance-example.html)

How can I reflect the [STATE](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f8096d499324cf0961f092944bbaedd05364eea1/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_control_status.ts#L30) of `CustomInputComponent` into the ngModel/ control of the `<input id="childInput">` inside the `template` of `CustomInputComponent`.

The reason I want this is because I have complicated template driven validators that I want to set on a (for e.g.) `CustomInputComponent` but the states "error, touched, etc ..." should be also apply to the nested inputs inside of the `CustomInputComponent`.

I hope its clear what im trying to achieve here.

In the Stackblitz as you will see:

If I type "43":

- The "parent control valid:" state is `false`.
- But the "child input valid:" state remains `true`.

### Edit:

I have added a case with a more complex template driven validation: (that is: parent control is only valid when inp1 and inp2 are even numbers)

[new Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mneerk-w3zltl).

Its works but I had to add line: (of course I need to unsubscribe!)

```
parentModel.control.statusChanges.subscribe(
  _ => this.ngModel.control.updateValueAndValidity()
);
```

in `ngAfterViewInit`, so that the child-input is updated when only inp1 and inp2 are alterated!

Comment: so, if I get this right, the valid/invalid state of the control in the nested component depends on the state of the field at the parent component?

Comment: No I was not precise enough. The component `CustomInputComponent` is a "form field" itself because I implement ControlValueAccessor. The state of `CustomInputComponent` itself should be in sync with its template Input with id=childInput. Its a little bit hard to explain.

Comment: you mean when you enter 43 customInputComponent not showing error?

Comment: The mat-input-field is not showing the error because only the component has pattern validator. But I want the Input (id=childinput) to inherit this error dynamically.

Comment: A couple of things that will help.  First, and _**most**_ importantly, put example code *in the question - not just in a link*.  By all means have a link to a working example, but the question *must* include enough code to demonstrate your problem.  When you just have a link and that link no longer works (which *will happen*), this question will become absolutely worthless.  Secondly, make your example clear by calling the elements parent and child, rather than calling them something else and referring to them as parent and child.  It's not clear what you actually want, and that will help.

Comment: I've made a detailed answer on a very similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806779/angular-2-large-scale-application-forms-handling/56375605#56375605

Comment: thanks @maxime1992 , I STARed and liked your answer here. Very promising.

Comment: Thanks @AndreElrico I appreciate the kind words!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the reference of the parent `ngModel` and the child `ngModel` in the child component, and then merge the validators. Unfortunately because you use the `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` you have to use the `Injector` to get the parent model:

[working example #1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mneerk-wze53k?file=app/custom-input/custom-input.component.ts)

```
export class CustomInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor { 
  @ViewChild(NgModel, { static: false }) ngModel: NgModel; 

  constructor(private _renderer: Renderer2, readonly injector: Injector) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const parentModel = this.injector.get(NgModel);

    this.ngModel.control.setValidators([
      this.ngModel.control.validator,
      parentModel.validator
    ]);

    this.ngModel.control.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
}
```

<sub>If you have any async validators, you should repeat the same procedure for these</sub>

If you don't want to use the `Injector`, there is another way to make your component use the `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR`, by setting it in the constructor instead of the decorator. Unfortunately a `setTimeout` is then necessary in the `ngAfterViewInit`, because this hook is child first than parent (as opposed to `ngOnInit`), and the validator will not yet be set properly:

[working example #2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mneerk-vcmm3n?file=app/custom-input/custom-input.component.ts)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-input',
  templateUrl: './custom-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-input.component.css']
})
export class CustomInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @ViewChild('inputElement', {static: false}) private _inputElement: ElementRef;
  get inputElement(): ElementRef {
    return this._inputElement;
  }

  @ViewChild(NgModel, { static: false }) ngModel: NgModel; 

  constructor(private _renderer: Renderer2, @Self() readonly parentModel: NgModel) {
     this.parentModel.valueAccessor = this;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.ngModel.control.setValidators([
        this.ngModel.control.validator,
        this.parentModel.control.validator
      ]);
      this.ngModel.control.updateValueAndValidity();
    }) 
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool this seems to work. But does this also work with complex template driven validators that dont necessarily have a "standalone validatorFN" (this means that validation only takes place inside of the directive). I will try to make an example.

Comment: May I also ask what `this.injector.get(NgModel);`. I find the DI topic rather complex.

Comment: It works with a dynamic pattern, which is updated after creation. The injector just injects a parent provider. There is some cyclic dependency which prevents this from doing so in the constructor, because of the `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR`

Comment: Thank you so far. I will test your solution and mark it as answer as soon as possible. [HERE!](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gs2k9h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquery-components-template.directive.ts) I have tried to make the opposite work. "Make parent false if any child is false". Its works but do you know if there is an more elegant way?

Comment: What wrapped my head the most. How do I get the QueryList<ngModel> from inside the directive. Can I query the host components view? (sorry for asking you that here :D )

Comment: @AndreElrico the elegant way for that is to just use a `<ng-form>`, and wrap your components in there